# Torch Divide Two Tensors With a Fallback Value if Unsafe - Fast

Tags: python, pytorch

I am dividing two tensors that include zeros with one another.

```py
test = torch.zeros(10000)
div = torch.div(test, test) # 99497.19it/s
```

However, the result `div` includes `nan`s, and using this output tensor messes up gradient decent, so I want to fill `div` with a fallback value of `0`.

```py
div[div != div] = 0 # 28546.27it/s
```

This operation for fixing the tensor is very costly, and changes the entire sequence from running 100,000 times a second to around 5500.

Is there a faster way to either divide with a fallback value, or fill out all `nan`s with `0`?